# Line break and inject span with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need help. I'm trying to achieve this effect with the headings of a site.

[image]

I tried by using background color and padding, but when the text grows in two or more lines it makes a big rectangle. I'm trying to figure out a way to break lines automatically into spans using javascript.

can anyone help me, please?

thanks a lot!

Comment: what will happen if the page size will grow? will desired solution should adjust its width to fit page size? Or is the width of your text area will be fixed?

Comment: it should resize, thats why i was thinking to use javascript :S

Comment: Please include your existing markup, preferably as a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.padded-multiline {
  line-height: 1.4;
  padding: 2px 0;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.padded-multiline span {
  background-color: #c0c;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0.45rem;
  line-height: 60px;
  /* Needs prefixing */
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="padded-multiline">
  <span>How do I add padding to subsequent lines of an inline text element?</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Just note the browser limitations here: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxdecorationbreak . Pretty good on the whole but not universal.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by adding `line-height` css property.

Here is the sample to achieve

```css
.hero-banner {
  background: url("https://www.tributemedia.com/hs-fs/hubfs/Images/Blog%20Images/shutterstock_252081805.jpg?width=2480&name=shutterstock_252081805.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.hero-banner span {
  background: #e7415e;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 55px;
  line-height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="hero-banner">
      <span>Join our 2020 Welcome change tour</span>
  </div>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achive this with CSS only then you need to set this element display attribute to inline like this:

```
display: inline;
```

You can also use the `line-height` CSS attribute together with the `font-size` to style the height of this `p` element (if you're using `p` for this text).
Make sure that `line-height` value is significantly bigger than the `font-size`.